# How to inject multiple views in a parent view with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a template for update.html with just a heading to see whether it works. 
I want to remove the div with id registerPageContent and add the div with id pdateTariffContent, which I want to be done on the event of clicking button updateButton.
I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: What's the scope of TariffView? Where is it being initialized and rendered. Figuring out this is the first step to figuring out why you cannot remove certain divs. Do you have a updateTariffView defined in backbone? If not, new updateTariffView() is not going to do anything.

Comment: Thanks. Figured that out :)
It works now